# Probabilities and expectations for paths of a certain length

Tags: probability, expected-value, random-graphs

If we are given a random graph G, where edges are made with probability $ \frac{1}{2}$.

A) What's the probability that $2$ different vertices have a path of length 2 between them.

B) What is the expected value of the number of paths of length 2 in the graph.

For A, would it simply be $ (\frac{1}{2})^2$ ?

For B, I know that there are (n-2) ways to choose a third vertex and that the probability of all three being connected is $ \frac{1}{2}^2$ but I am stuck.

Answer (score 1):

> A) What's the probability that 2 different vertices have a path of length 2 between them.

You need to count the possible two-edged paths between two particular vertices (ie: how many other vertices are there in the graph) and determine the probability that at least one among these paths is made.

> B) What is the expected value of the number of paths of length 2 in the graph.

You need to count the number of pairs, determine the expected count of length-2 paths between each pair, and then apply the linearity of expectation.

Answer (score 0):

Let $G(n+2,p)$ be a random graph of $n+2$ vertices where each edge is generated with probability $p$.Let $P'$ be the probability that there is no path of length $2$ between two chosen vertices.

Let $x,y$ be the chosen vertices. For any of the $n$ remaining vertices, say $z$, the probability that there is no length 2 path $x<->z<->y$ would be $1-p^{2}$.

So, $P' = (1-p^{2})^{n}$

So, the probability that there is a path of length 2 between any two chosen vertices is $1-P'=1-(1-p^{2})^{n}$.

Choosing $p=\frac{1}{2}$ would give you the required answer above.

As for the expected number of paths of length 2, consider two vertices $v$ and $w$, we'll find the expected number of paths of length 2 between these two vertices. Let $z$ be some other vertex. The probability that $v <-> z <-> w$ is an actual path in the graph is $\frac{1}{4}$.

So, we consider all such $v <-> z <-> w$. How many are there?, the answer is quite simple, it is the number of choices of $z$, i.e $n$.

Finally, the number of ways we can select two vertices is $C(n+2;2)$ so the expected number is:

$E = C(n+2;2) \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}1.\frac{1}{4}=C(n+2;2)\frac{n}{4}$